# How to edit value in a sub array

Tags: arrays, powershell, jagged-arrays

I can't understand this behavior in powershell :

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

""

$matrix =, @(, @("foo") * 5) * 3

$matrix[0][1] = "bar"

foreach($subArray in $matrix){
    Write-Host $($subArray[1])
}
```

With this script I'm initializing an array of 3 arrays, each containing 5 string "foo".

I want to set the 2nd element of the 1st array to "bar", and each arrays are affected :

```
# Returned :
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  1155    

bar
bar
bar
```

Is it a bug or am I missuntderstanding how arrays works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What the `*` operator de facto does with an array as the LHS is to use that array's elements *as-is* as the elements of the resulting array.**

In the case at hand, this means that **`$matrix[0]`, `$matrix[1]`, and `$matrix[2]` all point to the *same* 5-element array** composed of `"foo"` strings, so modifying that one array's elements will be reflected in all 3 `$matrix` elements.

This behavior is likely by design (see bottom section), and I am unaware of a concise workaround with the `*` syntax.

A viable **workaround** is:

```
# Note: The (...) around the arrays to replicate aren't strictly needed,
#       because `,` has higher precedence than `*`, but were added for
#       readability.
$nestedArrayTemplate = (, 'foo') * 5
$matrix = (, @()) * 3  # (, $null) * 3 would work too

for ($i=0; $i -lt $matrix.Count; ++$i) { $matrix[$i] = $nestedArrayTemplate.Clone() }
```

---

As an aside: **the above creates a *jagged array***, not a matrix (2-dimensional array). Here's how you would create a **true 2-dimensional array**:

```
$matrix = [string[,]]::new(3, 5) # PSv4-: New-Object string[] 3, 5
for ($row = 0; $row -lt $matrix.GetLength(0); ++$row) {
  for ($col = 0; $col -lt $matrix.GetLength(1); ++$col ){
    $matrix[$row, $col] = 'foo'
  }
}
```

Note that indexing into this 2-dimensional array then requires a *single* index expression with a *list* of indices; e.g., `[0, 1]` rather than `[0][1]`.

---

**Design musings**:

I can only speculate about the design intent, but I presume that *no* attempt is made to *clone* collections that happen to be the elements of the  LHS array, because there's no guarantee that such collections *can* be cloned - the same more generally applies to all element types of the LHS array that are *reference types* (other than strings).

With LHS array elements that are *value types* or *strings* - which is the more typical case - there's no problem, because the resulting array's elements will (effectively) be independent copies.

**In short: for predictable array replication with `*`, restrict the LHS array's element types to *value types* or *strings*.**

Comment: Thank you very much. You learnd me more than hoped. I just wanted a Jagged array because I didn't knew that real matrix where possible and built-in.

Comment: @Alsatian: Glad to hear it; my pleasure. PowerShell itself has no native multi-dimensional array support, but by virtue of its near-unlimited access to the underlying .NET framework, there are few limits on what you can do in PowerShell - if performance isn't a concern.